# How to get Gnome to open CD automatically

Tags: debian, gnome, compact-disc, nautilus

Having switched from Ubuntu back to Debian <sup>(a)</sup>, the one thing I miss is the auto-opening on CDs when inserted into the CD drive.

There's nothing immediately obvious under `System | Preferences` to do with device management.

How do I get these to open in Nautilus automatically?

---

<sup>(a)</sup> See "Unity fiasco" :-)

Comment: My solution to (a) was [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `System | Preferences` you want "Removable Drives and Media". Or maybe you need the Media tab under Nautilus `Edit | Preferences`. (I don't have Debian and couldn't quickly find out which of these is present in the current version.)

Comment: There is no removable drives and media in sys/preferences. But there _is_ a media tab in edit/prefs within Nautilus and, lo and behold, it's got a slew of action to be taken for audio cd, dvd-movie, data cd/dvd and so on. Thanks for that, cheers.